# C++ preprocessor directive issue

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

I have a stream class with following functions :

```
void writeInt(int value);                    //old function
void writeInt(int value, char* lable);       //new function
```

we've used the writeInt() old function in lot of places. without changing the existing usage
I tried to replace the old function with the new function using following:

```
#define      writeInt(x)          writeInt(x,#x)
```

but it still calls the old functions not the new functions!.

Update:(working test-case)

```
// IStream.h
#include <stdio.h>

class IWStream {

public:
    IWStream(char* path);
    virtual ~IWStream();

    virtual void    writeInt( int iValue, char* szlable= 0  );
private:
    FILE* _file;

};


//DataObject.h

class DataObject {

public:
    DataObject(int value);
    virtual ~DataObject(){};

    void writeData(IWStream *stream);

private:
    int _value;

};

//DataObject.cpp
#include "DataObject.h"
#include "IStream.h"

#define writeInt(x)     writeInt(x,#x)

DataObject::DataObject(int value)
{
    _value = value;
}

void DataObject::writeData(IWStream *stream)
{
    stream->writeInt(_value);
}


//main.cpp
int main(){

    IWStream stream("D://test.txt");

    DataObject data(10);
    data.writeData(&stream);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does your code even [compile](http://ideone.com/feBYQp)?

Comment: This should work, you must have made a mistake somewhere else. Can you post a test-case?

Comment: Got it to [work](http://ideone.com/wXdS79). You have to make sure you put the macro definition after both function declarations.

Comment: @MattMcNabb thanks for your reply, I created test-case but its working in that!. any how i'll post the code.

Comment: I meant post a test-case that shows the problem... hopefully you can look at the working test-case and figure out the difference between that and your broken code.